# Converting a task<T> to task<void>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ppl

Is there a way to simplify the following code to avoid the `.then` call that "converts" my `task<int>` to `task<void>`?

I can't change the function signature of `MyClass::MyFunction1` because it's a part of a public API.

```
task<void> MyClass::MyFunction1()
{
    return MyFunction2().then([](int) {});
}

task<int> MyClass::MyFunction2()
{
    // Some code here
}
```

Comment: What is `.then`?

Comment: @Drise A member function of `concurrency::task`

Answer (score 1):

`concurrency::task` is a template class, therefore `concurrency::task<int>` and `concurrency::task<void>` are two different classes. Instances of either cannot be cast or converted to the other.

Therefore your approach is somewhat correct. However, you're not converting, you're simply creating a new `task<void>` instance, which will be executed by the `task<int>` returned by `Method2()` after it is done. That hides a little bit what you're actually trying to do, and might make it harder to maintain the code in the future. I would think a better approach is to create and return a `task<void>` that encapsulates `Method2()` and waits for it's completion:

```
concurrency::task<void> MyFunction1()
{
    return concurrency::task<void>{[]()
    {
        MyFunction2().wait();
    }};
}
```

This is a bit more straight forward and clean, especially since the `task<void>` that the caller receives actually executes whatever `MyFunction2()` is executing.

Either way, since the types are not compatible, there is no way around creating a new `task<void>` instance.